# Why does Eclipse prompt that 'Editor does not contain Applet' everytime I run the following code? What's the fix?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, applet, processing

Note: I have the correct processing.core library imported on my project already with build paths created.

```
import processing.core.*; 

public class MyPApplet extends PApplet{

    private String URL = "https://www.bali.com/media/image/663/best-resorts-bali.jpg"; 
    private PImage backgroundImage; 

    public void setup() {
        size(400, 400); 
        backgroundImage = loadImage(URL, "jpg"); 
    }
    public void draw() { 
        image(backgroundImage, 0, 0); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you did integrate well processing in eclipse ?

Comment: Did you follow these steps : https://processing.org/tutorials/eclipse/ ?

Comment: @Calips Yeap, the core.jar library is part of my referenced libraries; I imported it according to the tutorial on processing.org/tutorials/eclipse.

Comment: Check my answer if it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer is half correct, but I think I understand why you were confused.

You **can** run Java code without a `main()` function, as long as that code is an applet. The problem is that your code is not an applet, so it requires a `main()` function.

This is a little bit confusing, because before Processing 3, `PApplet` did extend the `Applet` class, so a Processing sketch was an applet. But after Processing 3, that's no longer the case, so you can't run a Processing sketch as an applet. If you're following an outdated tutorial, that's the source of your confusion.

Also note that if you're using Processing from Java, you should use the `settings()` function instead of the `setup()` function.

Shameless self-promotion: I've written a tutorial on using Processing as a Java library available [here](http://HappyCoding.io/tutorials/java/processing-in-java).

Comment: That makes so much sense, because I'm following a course on coursera that uses an older version of processing and they don't need to use a main function; also, I'll definitely check out your tutorial. Thanks @KevinWorkman